# NET8 configuration validation (specially with arrays) using DataAnnotations

Tags: c#, arrays, validation, configuration, .net-8.0

I'm approaching to NET8 configuration validation using DataAnnotations, but I'm getting some obscure behaviors, specially with arrays, that I will show.

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Level": "One",
  "Levels": [
    "One",
    "Two",
    "Three",
    "Four"    
  ],
  "MoreLevel": 
    {
      "MoreLevel": "One"
    },
  
  "MoreLevels": [
    {
      "AnotherLevel": "One"
    },
    {
      "MoreLevel": "Two"
    },
    {
      "MoreLevel": "Three"
    },
    {
      "MoreLevel": "Four"
    }
  ]    
}
```

LevelEnum.cs

```
    public enum LevelEnum
    {
      Zero,
      One,
      Two,
      Three
    }
```

AppOptions.cs

```
public class AppOptions
  {
    [Required]
    public LevelEnum? Level { get; set; } = null;

    [Required]
    [ValidateObjectMembers]
    public MoreLevelOptions? MoreLevel { get; set; } = null;

    [Required]
    [ValidateObjectMembers]
    public List<LevelEnum?>? Levels { get; set; } = null;

    [Required]
    [ValidateObjectMembers]
    public List<MoreLevelOptions>? MoreLevels { get; set; } = null;    
  }
```

MoreLevelOptions.cs

```
  public class MoreLevelOptions
  {
    [Required]
    public LevelEnum? MoreLevel { get; set; } = null;
  }
```

Program.cs

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

  // Binding configuration
  builder.Services
    .AddOptions<AppOptions>()
    .Bind(builder.Configuration)
    .ValidateDataAnnotations()
    .ValidateOnStart();

  // Getting 'root' configuration
  AppOptions config = builder.Configuration.Get<AppOptions>();    

  // Building app
  var app = builder.Build();            

  // Runnin app
  app.Run();
}
```

Now, these are the things I don't get working:

### Wrong Enum name

Using `"Level": "One"` in appsetting.json validation works fine.
Using value `"Level": "Four"` I get the exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Failed to convert configuration value at 'Level' to type 'NET8Validation.LevelEnum'.'
FormatException: Four is not a valid value for LevelEnum.
ArgumentException: Requested value 'Four' was not found.
```

while executing line `AppOptions config = builder.Configuration.Get<AppOptions>();`
Fine, it works like expected, but I get the exception not at `.Bind()` time, but instead when I try to `.Get()` the configuration and map it to the `AppConfig` model.

Ok, I prefer to have the vaidation at the `.Bind()` moment, but that's is..

### [Required] attribute

If in appsettings.json I switch from

```
"Level": "One"
```

to

```
"NewLevel": "One"
```

the `.Bind()` method does not raise any exception, nor the `AppOptions config = builder.Configuration.Get<AppOptions>();` line.

Only when executing the very last `app.Run();` line I get the execption:

```
'DataAnnotation validation failed for 'AppOptions' members: 'Level' with the error: 'The Level field is required.'.'
```

Finally the `[Required]` validation attribute has been validated, but at the very end of the Main() method. In some cases it could bee to late to validate at this time.. How can I validate it earlier, at `.Bind()` time or `.Get<AppOptions>()` time?

Why `enum parse` and `[Required]` validation are made at different times in the app startup process?

### Wrong enum name in enum array

Looking at the appsettings.json section

```
"Levels": [
  "One",
  "Two",
  "Three",
  "Four"
]
```

I'm using `Four` as 4th element in the array, but as in the first case, `Four` is an unknown value in `LevelEnum` enum. I'm expecting the same exception

```
FormatException: Four is not a valid value for LevelEnum
```

as in the first case, but here there is any exception, the application starts successfully, and inside `Levels` array I get 3 items.

Why I get any `FormatException`, as in the first case? Why I finally get 3 items in `Level` fields, and the 1st element, instead of exception, is simply discarded?

It seems that validation works differently with `fields` and `arrays`, am I wrong?

### [Required] on object (class) field

Keep in mind that

```
public class AppOptions
{
  ..
  [Required]
  [ValidateObjectMembers]
  public MoreLevelOptions? MoreLevel { get; set; } = null;
  ..
}
```

and

```
public class MoreLevelOptions
{
  [Required]
  public LevelEnum? MoreLevel { get; set; } = null;
}
```

So `MoreLevel` object is required and `MoreLevel` field is also required.

If in appsettings.json I switch from

```
"MoreLevel": 
{
  "MoreLevel": "One"
}
```

to

```
"MoreLevel": 
{
  "AnotherLevel": "One"
}
```

while `[ValidateObjectMembers]` is present I get the `Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsValidationException` at `App.Run()` time, but if I comment out `//[ValidateObjectMembers]` same exception is raised anymore.

Now, really I need to decore all objects (classes) fields in appsettings.json model(s), to force the validation of all tree leafs?

### Wrong enum name in class array

Looking at the appsettings.json section mapped by `List<MoreLevelOptions>? MoreLevels { get; set; } = null;` field

```
"MoreLevels": [
  {
    "AnotherLevel": "One"
  },
  {
    "MoreLevel": "Two"
  },
  {
    "MoreLevel": "Three"
  },
  {
    "MoreLevel": "Four"
  }
]
```

I'm using `AnotherLevel` as field name of 1st item (this does not match corresponding `MoreLevel` [Required] field in MoreLevelOptions.cs) and `Four` value in 4th item.

I get any exceptions, neither for the 1st element (`MoreLevel` should be required) neither for the `Four` value (not existing in `LevelEnum.cs`).

Now, how can I get exceptions for this very same conditions already tested and working in flat fields (instead inside object fields)?

### Conclusions

I find very difficult to understand how validatio out-of-the-box works. My goal should be to decorate needing fields inside options model classes with [Required] and other data annotations attributes, and in a sigle place call the `.Bind()` or the `.Get<T>()` methods and be confident that **all** the validation are checked against **all** the decorated fields of my model(s).

Also, custom validation attributes I could inherit from `[ValidationAttribute]` seems never fire, nor at `.Bind()` nor at `.Get<T>()` nor at `.Run()` time.

So.. how I can simply get configuration validation working how I expect?

Comment: Sorry, but there is far too much text in this post, maybe someone will have the time but I suspect most people don't. You would be much better off with a [mre] that everyone can use.

Comment: ehm.. the initial code is the minimal reproducible example to cut/paste in a C# solution. Then test the only last "Wrong enum name in class array" case wich include them all. You will get no exceptions while you should..

Comment: Data annotations validation were initially designed for JSON/XML deserialization in the model binder, not the options pattern. If you want the property required you should not use a nullable ; have you tried with `public required T Property { get; init: }` instead ?

Comment: I can avoid the use of [Required] assigning a default value at field declaration time: that's fine with base types fields, but not with arrays! If I use default items at array declaration time, when binding configuration, I get that same declaring-time items + items coming from .json: it's a merge, I need a replace. And if .json array has enum values not parsable withinh the enum, no exception is raised: simply that item is removed silently, while same enum declaration in plain field (not array) raises the exception! Bad design, I mean!